# Amazon C# application using ec2, S3

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I want to implement the following :
On a Amazon S3, I have a large file containing information.
The processing required on it takes a lot of time(multiple days), using one machine. The requirement is to have an application that

dynamically registers Amazon EC2s(around 50) and splits the processing among them.
In order to replicate the same setup and processing application on all machines, I'm thinking of using
Amazon Machine Images. After each machine does the required processing, I want to post the result to another Amazon S3.

I've tried to do my homework and research all required aspects, but I have a few aspects that are not 100% clear to me.

Questions :
1. How can I setup an Amazon EC2s by using an image(Amazon Machine Image) (with C# code)
2. How can I pass parameters to an application running on a particular machine?( in order to segregate the processing
between machines).

Any other advices, corrections are very appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: You can host a `REST API` on your result machine, whenever a machine finish it job, it will send result via `API` to your result machine

Comment: Thanks Doan Cuong, that's a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to start a machine using EC2 and C# you can [follow this sample](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsNET/latest/DeveloperGuide/tutorial-spot-instances-net.html).

I suggest you to run them in the same [subnet](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/VPC_Subnets.html) so you can choose the best interprocess communication technology you want (Pipes, REST, WCF) and pass parameters to your applications running on an EC2 instance.

Comment: Thank you Scott for the solution, I'm checking the link right now.